# Python number starting with 0

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
>>> a = 02492
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid token


>>> a = 02132
>>> print a
1114
```

Comment: because of 0 at the start.

Comment: [Syntax for octal numbers changed in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers), use `0o2492`.

Comment: @Ashwini it shows syntax error for me.

Comment: In the first statement also has a leading zero . but that occur a error. but the second statement also a value with leading zero but it shown value like this? Whats the background reason for that.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Oops! I missed that OP is using 9 in an octal number.

Comment: @VarnanK Integer literals starting with 0 are octal numbers in Python 2, and you cannot have 9 in base 8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A leading zero means an *octal* number, which is one that allows the digits `0` through `7` inclusive,

So, while `02132` is a valid octal number, `02492` is *not,* because it contains the non-digit (in the context of octal numbers) character `9`.

It's no different from asking a computer to process a decimal number such as:

```
num = 3v14159
```

---

You should also be careful with things like `02132` - it is *not* the same as the decimal number `2132`, rather it's the octal variant `2x83 + 1x82 + 3x81 + 2x80`, or `1114`.

Comment: Then what happens in the first statement ?

Comment: @VarnanK, it cmplains that you're trying to create an octal number from non-octal digits. The second value works because `2`, `1`, `3` and `2` (again) _are_ valid octal digits.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable information. I have one more doubt , I want to assign that value (02492) to an variable how can it possible. I'm tried int(02492) then also it showing syntax error

Comment: Why it is not take as hexadecimal ?

Comment: @Varnan K,
hex number: `0x0123456789abcdef`;
octal: `01234567` (`0o01234567` in version 3k), but no 8 or 9;
decimal: `0123456789`